# Hiding Checkbox & Assigning Value - Ruby on Rails - Easy Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying to hide a checkbox and assign a default value of 1 such that the submit button only shows. Here is my form. Just wondering as the proper format as I am new to rails. I think you can do this with helpers but was wondering if I can just include it in the form. Here is the form:

```
<% remote_form_for [@post, Vote.new] do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :vote %>
        <%= f.check_box :vote %>
    </p>
    <%= f.submit "Vote" %>
```

Comment: I don't get your question. Why do you want a checkbox if it wont be shown and will always be 1?

Comment: So when the user clicks the submit button "Vote," you want the params hash to have {:vote => '1'} in it, but without the checkbox showing. Is that right? Or do you just want a way to tell that they clicked on the submit button?

Comment: You can tell I am new. I am trying to allow them to vote up. So the submit button will say "like" and when they click it delivers "1" to table. Then I display the count on the return. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can certainly do this, but if all you want is to set a parameter without displaying a field, what you probably want instead is a hidden field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :vote, :value => '1' %>
```

If you really do want a hidden checkbox (maybe so you can optionally display it later using javascript?), you can do it like this:

```
<%= f.check_box :vote, :checked => true, :style => 'visibility: hidden' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to hide the checkbox:

```
<%= f.check_box_tag :vote, 1, true, :style => "display: none;" %>
```

But if you just want to pass a value you can just use a hidden field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field_tag, :vote, 1 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass the value along, use a hidden field

```
<% remote_form_for [@post, Vote.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field_tag 'vote', '1' %>
  <%= f.submit "Vote" %>
<% end %>
```